# How can I know which Sentinel Tile is further north?

Tags: coordinate-system, tiles, copernicus, esa

Sentinel divides the planet surface into tiles, represented in the figure below. I was wondering if there is a programmatic way to compare two of those tile ids and "calculate" which is further north?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function that extracts and compares the last letter of each id.
The tile whose letter has the highest lexicographic order, is further north than the other.